# Using 2 gridviews in android

Tags: android, gridview

enter code hereI'm using 2 gridview one gridview with 9X9 cells and one with 3x3 cells.
I've set the 9x9 grid with `imageview`s *(in total there are 81 imageviews)* and 3x3 are there 9 imageviews.

When I clicked in the 9x9 grid it displays the images in their respective place.
Now what I can't figure out how to display the image in a 3x3 grid when a condition is met in the 9x9 grid. It's basically a tic tac toe game being played now 9 games are being played at one time between 2 people and when one set is won I want to show the winner of that set over the game

[image: what i want]

I've attached a picture what I want. The 3x3 gridview is overlapping the 9x9 gridview.

my codes are below

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.auk01.tictactoegrand.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.auk01.tictactoegrand.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<GridLayout
android:id="@+id/GrandGridLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="3"
android:rowCount="3"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSet0"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSet1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSet2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSet3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSet4"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSet5"
    android:layout_width="116dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSet6"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSet7"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSet8"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

</GridLayout>

<GridLayout
android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:background="@drawable/board9"
android:columnCount="9"
android:rowCount="9"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView0"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="3"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="4"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="5"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="6"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="7"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="8"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="9"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="10"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

//i have removed id/imageView11 to imageView75 just to explain my code in shoter
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView76"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="76"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView77"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="77"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView78"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="78"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView79"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="79"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView80"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="gamelogic"
    android:tag="80"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/invisable" />

</GridLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/WinnerLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="35dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="PlayAgain"
    android:text="Play Again" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.auk01.tictactoegrand;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int ActivePlayer = 0; // 0 for red
int[] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};//2 means unplayed.
int[][] WinningLocation0 = {{0,1,2}, {9,10,11}, {18,19,20}, {0,9,18}, {1,10,19}, {2,11,20}, {0,10,20}, {2,10,18}};
int[][] WinningLocation1 = {{3,4,5}, {12,13,14}, {21,22,23}, {3,12,21}, {4,13,22}, {5,14,23}, {3,13,23}, {5,13,21}};
int[][] WinningLocation2 = {{6,7,8}, {15,16,17}, {24,25,26}, {6,15,24}, {7,16,25}, {8,17,26}, {6,16,26}, {8,16,24}};
int[][] WinningLocation3 = {{27,28,29}, {36,37,38}, {45,46,47}, {27,36,45}, {28,37,46}, {29,38,47}, {27,37,47}, {29,37,45}};
int[][] WinningLocation4 = {{30,31,32}, {39,40,41}, {48,49,50}, {30,39,48}, {31,40,49}, {32,41,50}, {30,40,50}, {32,40,48}};
int[][] WinningLocation5 = {{33,34,35}, {42,43,44}, {51,52,53}, {33,42,51}, {34,43,52}, {35,44,53}, {33,43,53}, {35,43,51}};
int[][] WinningLocation6 = {{54,55,56}, {63,64,65}, {72,73,74}, {54,63,72}, {55,64,73}, {56,65,74}, {54,64,74}, {56,64,72}};
int[][] WinningLocation7 = {{57,58,59}, {66,67,68}, {75,76,77}, {57,66,75}, {58,67,76}, {59,68,77}, {57,67,77}, {59,67,75}};
int[][] WinningLocation8 = {{60,61,62}, {69,70,71}, {78,79,80}, {60,69,78}, {61,70,79}, {62,71,80}, {60,70,80}, {62,70,78}};
boolean GameOver = false;

public void gamelogic(View view) {
    ImageView tappedview = (ImageView) view;

    int tappedLocation = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());

    if(gameState[tappedLocation] == 2 && !GameOver) {
        gameState[tappedLocation] = ActivePlayer;
        tappedview.setTranslationY(-3000f);
        if (ActivePlayer == 0) {
            tappedview.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            ActivePlayer = 1;
        } else if (ActivePlayer == 1) {
            tappedview.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            ActivePlayer = 0;
        }
        tappedview.animate().translationYBy(3000f).setDuration(10);


    }
    String msg = "";
    for (int[]WinningPosition : WinningLocation0){
        if(gameState[WinningPosition[0]] == gameState[WinningPosition[1]]
                && gameState[WinningPosition[1]] == gameState[WinningPosition[2]]
                && gameState[WinningPosition[0]] !=2){

            if(ActivePlayer == 0)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "0 IS THE WINNER Of Set Zero", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                GridLayout GrandGridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.GrandGridLayout);
                msg = "0 IS THE WINNER";
            if(ActivePlayer == 1)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "X IS THE WINNER Of Set Zero", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                msg = "X IS THE WINNER";
        }
    }

    for (int[]WinningPosition : WinningLocation1){
        if(gameState[WinningPosition[0]] == gameState[WinningPosition[1]]
                && gameState[WinningPosition[1]] == gameState[WinningPosition[2]]
                && gameState[WinningPosition[0]] !=2){

            if(ActivePlayer == 0)
                msg = "0 IS THE WINNER";
            if(ActivePlayer == 1)
                msg = "X IS THE WINNER";

            LinearLayout WinnerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.WinnerLayout);
            WinnerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            TextView WinnerMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            WinnerMsg.setText(msg);
            GameOver = true;
        }
    }

}

public void PlayAgain(View view){
    LinearLayout WinnerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.WinnerLayout);
    WinnerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    GameOver = false;
    ActivePlayer = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < gameState.length; i++)
        gameState[i] = 2;
    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
    for(int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
        ((ImageView)gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    LinearLayout WinnerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.WinnerLayout) ;
    WinnerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

this is all the code now i cant figure out how to get the drawable\red in small gridview which in my case id.grandgridlayout (3x3) 
id.gridlayout is 9x9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not discuss the logic of the program itself or the "right" pattern to use.
I've just created a simple app that in case the three X on the top left corner are checked when you click one time on the grid view where there are some data preloaded. After click you'll see the new X appear on the little grid below the big grid.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#C0C0C0"
tools:context="com.ad3luc.problemsolving.AMain">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView_big"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="9"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_below="@id/gridView_big"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView_small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

AMain.java

```
public class AMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GridView gGridViewBig;
    private GridView gGridViewSmall;

    static final String[] ticTacToeBig = new String[] {
            "X", "O", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "X", "", "O", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "X", "O", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "X", "", "", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "O", "", "",
            "", "", "X", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "O", "", "", "", "O", "X", "X",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "O", "",
            "", "", "", "", "", "", "X", "", "O"
    };

    static final String[] ticTacToeSmall = new String[] {
            "", "", "",
            "", "", "",
            "", "", "",
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gGridViewBig = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView_big);
        gGridViewSmall = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView_small);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterBig = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ticTacToeBig);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSmall = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ticTacToeSmall);

        gGridViewBig.setAdapter(adapterBig);
        gGridViewSmall.setAdapter(adapterSmall);

        gGridViewBig.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                if(ticTacToeBig[0].equals("X") && ticTacToeBig[9].equals("X") && ticTacToeBig[18].equals("X")) {

                    ticTacToeSmall[0] = "X";
                    gGridViewSmall.setAdapter(adapterSmall);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I think the solution to implement is to read the current click made on the big grid and match with a list, map, ... where you are storing all the click. When condition is matched you need to update the the list, map, ... that you'll pass to the adapter that then you'll pass to the small gridview.